# What's the difference between WordNet 3.1 and WordNet 3.0?

Tags: nlp, wordnet

There doesn't seem to be a changelog or something of that sort available at wordnet.princeton.edu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to @abarisone's answer, the actual synset IDs themselves can differ between WordNet 3.0 and WordNet 3.1 :(

For example, in WordNet 3.1 a **chair** is [**103005231-n**](http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn31/103005231-n).

However, in WordNet 3.0 it *was* **103001627-n**. But you cannot look that up in http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn31/103001627-n nor http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/103001627-n, but instead you need to use http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/03001627-n which incorrectly redirects to [**102992974-n**](http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn31/102992974-n).

I think it's a bug in [WordNet RDF 3.1 online app](http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/), because [**102992974-n**](http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn31/102992974-n) doesn't officially exist. You can't even search for it (both online and offline). And if you get the RDF/JSON-LD file on that page, it gives you **103005231-n**.

In `wn3.1.dict/dict/index.noun` :

```
chair n 5 4 @ ~ %p + 5 2 03005231 00599171 10488547 03275941 03005700
```

There's no mention of `02992974` anywhere in that file.

Both of these issues are confusing. I wonder why they changed synset IDs in minor revision.

---

Regarding status of WordNet synset IDs:

Conclusion is, currently, using WordNet 3.0 synset IDs is safest.

For future work, can consider using Inter-Lingual Index from [Global Wordnet Association](http://globalwordnet.org) (coming soon). Which will have IDs compatible with Wordnet 3.0.

References from [wn-users mailing list, 30 Oct 2015](https://lists.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A1=ind1510&L=wn-users#2):

> From: Raphael, Nicholas
>
> The URI is built from the “dblocation” field, which is a byte offset
>   from the beginning of the relevant character-based database file (I’m
>   not sure which). This will change from release to release as items are
>   removed and added and moved around.

.

> From: Peter Clark
>
> To the best of my knowledge….   FYI a little known fact is that the
>   sense keys (e.g., “ability%1:07:00::”) are stable between releases,
>   except when senses are split or merged. This provides a stable way to
>   refer to synsets across releases, rather than use synset numbers. Also
>   you can find the mappings between synset numbers in different releases
>   by looking for the same sense keys.   (sensekey->synset is a many-to-1
>   mapping: A synset may have multiple sense keys, one for each
>   word+sense in the synset. But a sense key maps to exactly one synset).
>   Best wishes, Pete

.

> From: John McCrae
>
> Hello Hendy,
>
> Yes WordNet synset Identifiers are based on the byte offset of the
>   descriptor in a given release of WordNet, as such they are far from
>   stable across versions of WordNets. The sense identifiers are more
>   stable but still can be unreliable as sense do get split and merged.
>   Also, there are two slightly different versions of WordNet 3.1 and the
>   WordNet RDF version accepts synset identifiers from either... this is
>   of course, as others have commented, all very confusing.
>
> For this reason, the Global WordNet Association has started work on an
>   Inter-Lingual Index, which we expect to be online soon (i.e., in time
>   for the Global WordNet Conference in January), and will give each
>   synset a single unchanging URI.
>
> Piek Vossen gave a good talk about this recently and this slides are
>   online here: http://ldl2014.org/slides/Vossen-LOD-CILI.pdf
>
> For the moment, I would recommend using WN 3.0 identifiers to link
>   synsets, which the WordNet Interlingual Index will also be based on.
>
> Regards, John

Comment: Global WordNet Association Inter-Lingual Index: https://github.com/globalwordnet/ili

Answer (score 1):

If you look under [WordNet's Current Version section](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/) you'll find that:

> The most recent Windows version of WordNet is 2.1, released in March
>   2005. Version 3.0 for Unix/Linux/Solaris/etc. was released in December, 2006. Version 3.1 is currently available only online.

Moreover, talking about the difference between version 3.0 and 3.1 you can read:

> WordNet 3.1 DATABASE FILES ONLY
>
> You can download the WordNet 3.1 database files from here. Note that
>   this is not a full package as those above, nor does it contain any
>   code for running WordNet. However, you can replace the files in the
>   database directory of your 3.0 local installation with these files and
>   the WordNet interface will run, returning entries from the 3.1
>   database. This is simply a compressed tar file of the WordNet 3.1
>   database files.

So the difference is that WordNet 3.1 is online only, but you can replace the 3.0 version database and use a local installation.

You can find documentation about version 3.0 [here](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/documentation/).